# Angular 4 Create Dynamic formArray inside array using reactive forms

Tags: forms, angular

Here, we are creating dynamically form array's inside array.

Below is the sample structure of expected result given below.

```
{
  "optionsRadios": null,
  "Package_Title": null,
  "HotelData": [
    {
      "Htitle": "",
      "HDescription": "",
      "hotelStar": "",
"RoomData": [
    {
      "Hotel_Room_Type": ""
    },
    {
      "Hotel_Room_Type": ""
    }
  ]
    }
  ]

}
```

I want to create HotelData Dynamically, within that HotelData array i want to create RoomData array fields also dynamically.

I created HotelData fields by the following codes:

```
    export class AddPackageComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
            this.invoiceForm = this._formBuild.group({
    Package_Title: [],
                HotelData: this._formBuild.array([this.addRows()])
    })
    }
    addRows() {
            return this._formBuild.group({
                Htitle: [''],
                HDescription: [''],
                hotelStar: ['']
            });

        }
addHotel() {
            const control: FormArray = this.invoiceForm.get(`HotelData`) as FormArray;
            control.push(this.addRows());
        }
    }
```

Comment: i followed #Rahul Singh answer but, I'm getting error like in browser TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right track, we just need to add some more code...

`addRows` need the form array RoomData, and here we also initially push an empty form group of room. If you don't want that, modify it.

```ts
addRows() {
  let group = this._formBuild.group({
    ...
    RoomData: this._formBuild.array([])
  });
  // push formgroup to array initially
  this.addRoom(group.controls.RoomData)
  return group;
}
```

`addRoom` looks like this:

```ts
addRoom(hotel:any) {
  let group = this._formBuild.group({
    Hotel_Room_Type: ['']
  })
  hotel.push(group)
}
```

`addRoom` is also the method we are calling from template when we want to add a new room to a hotel. Remember to pass the current hotel as parameter from template.

As for adding a new hotel, your `addHotel` stays the way you have it now.

Then over to your template, the relevant part should look something like this:

```html
<div formArrayName="HotelData">
  <div *ngFor="let hotel of invoiceForm.get('HotelData').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" >
    <!-- form controls here -->
    <button (click)="addRoom(hotel.get('RoomData'))">Add Room</button>
    <div formArrayName="RoomData">
      <div *ngFor="let room of hotel.get('RoomData').controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
        <!-- form controls here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, here's a Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7tcLcnzALew3oKGenjwK?p=preview

Comment: Here,`<div formArrayName="HotelData">
                    <div *ngFor="let hotel of invoiceForm.controls.HotelData.controls;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i"></div></div>` is placed as suggested by you but, here get an error like "Identifier 'HotelData' is not defined".

Comment: Have you checked the plunker that your code match? That error is unfamiliar for me, never seen it before, so based on the error I cannot really help. Perhaps you can modify the plunker with your code, if you are able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I followed your given code it's working fine development. But in Production am getting error like this `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

Comment: Above issue has been cleared. But, how to remove RoomData in HotelData, i tried like this `removeRooms(i: number,j: number,invoiceForm) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls[`RoomData`];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }` give me any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a ton. FormArray and FormGroup and indexing was irritating

Comment: @AJT_82 please help me on this related question . i have seen your many answers are powerful related to form array in angular reactive form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511205/how-can-i-patch-data-to-check-boxes-array-in-angular-4-5 . thanks a lot any suggestion would be appreciated