# how to store multiple row values without pushing in angular 6?

Tags: angular

My html file for storing form array value.

```
<tr  *ngFor="let item of data['selectedValue']; let i = index"> 
    <td>{{item.Candidate_FN}}</td>
    <td>
        <mat-form-field>
            <select matNativeControl placeholder="Not Hired Reason" formControlName="Reason">
                <option *ngFor="let item of LkupNotHiredReason" value="{{item.Code}}" selected>{{item.Description}}</option>                        
            </select>               
        </mat-form-field>        
    </td>
    <td>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 390px;"> 
            <input  matInput placeholder="Remarks" formControlName="Remarks">
        </mat-form-field>        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick();">Cancel</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

in data['selectedValue'] comes multiple array. i need to store form value dynamically in database.but not push method. how can i store this form array value in angular 6?

Comment: Use angular reactive forms. Check this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010904/3983941

Comment: i followed similar code as you mentioned link. now its working